How to fix point cloud orientation with the xyz orientation
I want to rotate the point cloud of a face so when I align it with others is close, the face orientation was acquired with mediapipe on the original image, I'm using open3d for the point cloud.
Example of one point cloud:
Angle x: 3.3287784739315622
Angle y: 5.251647240185689
Angle z: -0.0819800692880541


Use https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz.html to get rotation matrix and apply the rotation using https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html#open3d.geometry.PointCloud.rotate
